# How do I search TFS for a word without 'getting' the project?

Tags: tfs

I often have occasion to search for a function name in a project that I haven't retrieved from Team Foundation Server (TFS) and that I don't want to retrieve. Is there a way to search for that function name (any word) on TFS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Does this answer your question?

[Find in Files: Search all code in Team Foundation Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039/find-in-files-search-all-code-in-team-foundation-server)

Good luck,

Martin.