# How to list files of a team project using tfs api?

Tags: c#, api, tfs

I am wondering if there is a way for me to list all 'files' containted in a tfs team project. What I am aiming to do is search for files of a particular name that dont have fixed paths within TFS caused by branching ($/MyTeamProject/Main/Build/instruction.xml and $/MyTeamProject/Branches/Release_1.0). Once a file would be found I would like to manipulate it.

I guess that we are talking items when it comes to entities containted within a team project and not traditional files and therefore this might be a bit tricky?

I have seen some samples for manipulating a file but all samples so far have fixed paths.

Answer (score 17):

This is not a different answer, but simply an upgrade of Vengafoo's code. The TeamFoundationServer class is obsolete in 2011 (not sure when this happened, I just know it is obsolete as of now). Vengafoo's code is from 2009, so that makes sense. Use the TfsTeamProjectCollection class with the TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory factory class instead.

Here is the upgrade, just one line of change:

```
//TeamFoundationServer server = new TeamFoundationServer("server");
TfsTeamProjectCollection server = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory.GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://tfsServerURI:8080/tfs/"));

VersionControlServer version = server.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer)) as VersionControlServer;

ItemSet items = version.GetItems(@"$\ProjectName", RecursionType.Full);
//ItemSet items = version.GetItems(@"$\ProjectName\FileName.cs", RecursionType.Full);

foreach (Item item in items.Items)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(item.ServerItem);
}
```

Comment: version.GetItems(@"$\ProjectName", RecursionType.Full)
This also works: version.GetItems(@"$/ProjectName", RecursionType.Full) --- so either slash or backslash works

Answer (score 8):

Here is how I've figured out how to list all the files of a TFS Project:

Add Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client and Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client as a reference to your project.

Add a using for Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client and Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client

```
TeamFoundationServer server = new TeamFoundationServer("server");
VersionControlServer version = server.GetService(typeof(VersionControlServer)) as VersionControlServer;

ItemSet items = version.GetItems(@"$\ProjectName", RecursionType.Full);
ItemSet items = version.GetItems(@"$\ProjectName\FileName.cs", RecursionType.Full);

foreach (Item item in items.Items)
{
    System.Console.WriteLine(item.ServerItem);
}
```

The second GetItems will restrict the items found to those of a specific filename. I just have this sample outputting the server path for all of the files found.