# How to search through source code in TFS?

Tags: search, tfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Find in Files: Search all code in Team Foundation Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039/find-in-files-search-all-code-in-team-foundation-server)

What solution are exists to provide an ability to search through some or all TFS repository using some Web interface?

Currently I have only one idea: checking-out target TFS branches on server running [Microsoft Search Server](http://www.microsoft.com/enterprisesearch/en/us/search-server-express.aspx) which provides SharePoint-like web interface to perform a search.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing built-in for searching within the code.  If you install the [TFS Power Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963.aspx), it gives you the ability to search for files based on wildcard name.

Comment: Yea, I saw this ability. But from my experience - it isn't a reliable solution

Comment: you could use this tool for search functionality    http://tfssearchcode.codeplex.com/

Comment: tfssearchcode.codeplex.com doesn't work ! It throws exception !