# Microsoft TFS research

Tags: tfs

I have to do a research in TFS to identify all the sources in which the recurrence "word" is present.
How can I do a general research in TFS, without mapping everything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No such a built-in feature in TFS 2010.

Just as Daniel said you need to map the source code to local workspace then search with VS or other plugins/tools. Such as [TFS Administrators Toolkit for VS 2010](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-13988.TFSAdministratorsToolkitforVS2010). Refer to this thread for details: [TFS 2010 and VS 2010 searching code in source control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880151/tfs-2010-and-vs-2010-searching-code-in-source-control)

Alternately you can consider upgrading to TFS 2017 or later version. Code Search feature is integrated in them. See [Search across all your code and work items](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/search/overview?view=vsts) for details.

Answer (score 0):

In TFS 2010? You have no choice, you have to grab all of the source code.

If you were to use a modern version of TFS (2017 or 2018), you could use the Code Search feature to easily do exactly what you're asking.