# How to update a stored procedure in a shared dataset used by multiple report projects at once?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, stored-procedures, reporting-services

**Situation:**
We can use the same shared dataset in different SSRS projects. We can deploy updated shared dataset to the same location on the web from multiple different projects. This is ok.

**The problem:** If we update shared dataset for one project (changing stored procedure that it uses) - how will we know where else in another projects the same dataset is used and needs to be updated. We don't know how to update shared dataset in all projects at once so they all use the same stored procedure after update. Do I have to go to each report project and update shared dataset manually?

**Example.** We have 2 projects:
 
 - *Report_AB*
 - *Report_DE*

Both use the same shared dataset: *common_dataset*. Both use also the same dataset deployment path: *ServerName/Shared Data Sets*

Then, in project *Report_AB* i go to the above dataset properties and change stored procedure behind it from *stored_procedure_01* to *stored_procedure_02*.

After all my changes have been made I will check that into TFS.

*Common_dataset* in project *Report_DE* will stay still the same - so I would have to go to that report project and update that dataset as well and also check that in.

What if I have 5 different report projects using the same dataset and I don't really remember which ones are the ones that use it?? Do I have to go one by one and find them all first and then update shared dataset for each of those report projects?

Comment: You should be able to search your RDL files, either from within visual studio or using a text search tool like fnr.exe and look for the proc name.

Comment: You might also want to start documenting your report architecture.

Comment: Thank you Nick - this is a good idea to start with and it works. I used "Find - by Wildcard" functionality in TFS and gave me all the files that use given stored procedure. The perfect solution would be that when you check in - it would check automatically (or after ticking some tick box) if any other datasets use that stored procedure and if yes and a developer agrees - it would change it automatically everywhere else. Just a thought.

Comment: Actually, I've been a bit too quick in saying it works for me. This gives me stored procedures files themselves in other database projects that I have in TFS, but it doesn't give me result of files containing that string. Therefore I would need more some solution to find inside the files. Here is the reference to that topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039/find-in-files-search-all-code-in-team-foundation-server

Comment: They're in your RDL files in text form. I recall searching them from visual studio (not TFS). You could also _get_ all the RDL and do a windows search on it