# Do shared data sets in TFS automatically update across all copies in same solution?

Tags: reporting-services, tfs, visual-studio-2017

If I add an existing shared data set that exists in another folder within the same solution in TFS, is this newly added shared data set still linked to the original? If changes are made to the original data set, do those changes also update to the copy I added in my folder?

The reason I ask is that when designing my report, this shared data set was not available. I don't want to recreate the wheel, so I was hoping I could just add the existing item to my folder, and it would still update as changes were made to the original.

Hopefully this makes sense, id be more than happy to elaborate if needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually no, TFS will not automatically update across all copies in same solution.

You may need to manually or use script to search RDL files in TFS server.

Please also take a look at this similar question here:[How to update a stored procedure in a shared dataset used by multiple report projects at once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34630812/how-to-update-a-stored-procedure-in-a-shared-dataset-used-by-multiple-report-pro)