# How can you identify which project produces a particular dll?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

Is there anyway within Visual Studio / TFS to identify which project produces which dll?

I'm aware you can look under a particular project's properties and see what the name of the dll is, but in the circumstance where you have loads and loads of projects this doesn't seem very efficient.

I've got the situation where I've got a project that references a dll, which includes a method I want to examine, but I don't know what project produces this dll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Unfortunately, no.** The only way I know is that you may could use a decompile extension. (Strongly not recommend to use) Through the source code after decompile, you can view namespace and judge which project produces the dll. (Under normal circumstances)

And you may also have to face some problems such as:

- Legal issues
- Need to pay for the extension
- Only work for C#/.Net
- The source code may be confusion and not standard

Answer (score 0):

This should be a one time activity, you can go ahead and take a look into the project file, in case of C# project the csproj file.

If you do not want to do it opening each file, then i would say write a small tool to read all the project files and look for the  name.
BTW, this will be different for different projects, and you need to find out the proper location to look.

Comment: There is a content search code sample described [in this blog entry circa 2012](http://pascallaurin42.blogspot.co.za/2012/05/tfs-queries-searching-in-all-files-of.html) which was the basis for an answer in a SO question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039/find-in-files-search-all-code-in-team-foundation-server), applicable depending on the client api version used.