# versioncontrol.GetAllTeamProjects() returning 0

Tags: c#, tfs

I'm working on a project where I'll have a C# application search all TFS project's .cs files for a string or string patterns. I found some code that looks similar to what I was looking to do [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039/find-in-files-search-all-code-in-team-foundation-server)

```
namespace TFSSearch
{
class Program
{
    static string[] textPatterns = new[] { "void main(", "exception", "RegisterScript" };  //Text to search
    static string[] filePatterns = new[] { "*.cs", "*.xml", "*.config", "*.asp", "*.aspx", "*.js", "*.htm", "*.html", 
                                           "*.vb", "*.asax", "*.ashx", "*.asmx", "*.ascx", "*.master", "*.svc"}; //file extensions

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory
             .GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("https://{tfsserver}/tfs"));

            tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();

            var versionControl = tfs.GetService<VersionControlServer>();


            StreamWriter outputFile = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Find.txt");
            var allProjs = versionControl.GetAllTeamProjects(true);
            foreach (var teamProj in allProjs)
            {
                foreach (var filePattern in filePatterns)
                {
                    var items = versionControl.GetItems(teamProj.ServerItem + "/" + filePattern, RecursionType.Full).Items
                                .Where(i => !i.ServerItem.Contains("_ReSharper"));  //skipping resharper stuff
                    foreach (var item in items)
                    {
                        List<string> lines = SearchInFile(item);
                        if (lines.Count > 0)
                        {
                            outputFile.WriteLine("FILE:" + item.ServerItem);
                            outputFile.WriteLine(lines.Count.ToString() + " occurence(s) found.");
                            outputFile.WriteLine();
                        }
                        foreach (string line in lines)
                        {
                            outputFile.WriteLine(line);
                        }
                        if (lines.Count > 0)
                        {
                            outputFile.WriteLine();
                        }
                    }
                }
                outputFile.Flush();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string ex = e.Message;
            Console.WriteLine("!!EXCEPTION: " + e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Continuing... ");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("========");
        Console.Read();
    }

    // Define other methods and classes here
    private static List<string> SearchInFile(Item file)
    {
        var result = new List<string>();

        try
        {
            var stream = new StreamReader(file.DownloadFile(), Encoding.Default);

            var line = stream.ReadLine();
            var lineIndex = 0;

            while (!stream.EndOfStream)
            {
                if (textPatterns.Any(p => line.IndexOf(p, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0))
                    result.Add("=== Line " + lineIndex + ": " + line.Trim());

                line = stream.ReadLine();
                lineIndex++;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            string ex = e.Message;
            Console.WriteLine("!!EXCEPTION: " + e.Message);
            Console.WriteLine("Continuing... ");
        }

        return result;
    }
}
}
```

The problem I'm having is when I try to get the projects using **versionControl.GetAllTeamProjects(true);** allProjs seems to get no information back. It is an empty array of TeamProject. When I debug, tfs.HasAuthenticated is true and it doesn't throw any exceptions. The TFS server is on a https domain. How can I make sure I'm exactly connecting to TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I test at my side, everything works correctly.

1. Install the Nuget package
   [Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient/15.112.1) by running below
   command in **Package Manager Console**:

   `PM>  Install-Package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient -Version 15.112.1`
2. Make sure you specify the correct TFS server,

   eg : `http://servername:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection`

Then check it again.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I found out that our TFS is using Git, which is what I believe to be the problem. Do you have any ideas of what I need to change to get that to work?

Comment: @BryanMcneil I investigate this but cannot find a way to search the Git as TFVC projects even with the GIT client API used (GetService<GitRepositoryService>()). If you are using TFS 2017, you can use Code Search feature.

Comment: Thanks for help. I'll look into adding the Code Search feature.