# Is there a way to search the text inside of every file in TFS 2013?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, replace, tfs

I followed [Find in Files: Search all code in Team Foundation Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41039/find-in-files-search-all-code-in-team-foundation-server)

But Could not find a solution for TFS2013.

Is there a way to search the text inside of every file in TFS 2013 for a specific string ?

Currently I perform a Get Latest on the entire codebase and use Windows Search, but this gets quite painful with over Large number of files occupying GB's of memory.

Answer (score 3):

Code search feature was added in TFS 2015. For TFS 2013, the following extension by Mattias is an excellent tool

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-13988.TFSAdministratorsToolkitforVS2013